# Kubernetes: multiple domain setup and loadbalancer/ingress strategy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

How is it possible to use more than one domain in the same cluster?

At the moment I've running ONE cluster with **one domain** pointing to a hardware `loadbalancer` and `traefik` as an `ingress-controller`.

Now I wanna add a second domain pointing to different workloads/services.

Do I need

1. a second `ingress-controller` with a second `LoadBalancer` (and pointing the second domain to that second LB)?
2. to point the second domain to the same first `LoadBalancer` to use only one ìngress-controller`?

I am asking, because I have troubles when pointing the second domain to the second `Loadbalancer` and pointing that one to the existing `ingress-controller` (nothing happens)
But when I point my **second domain**, to the first Loadbalancer, it seems working as expected.

*(My guess is: solution "2")?*

(I wanna keep one Ingress-controller, thought I need two loadbalanacers)

Does this have to do with the occupied ports 443 and 80?

Thank you

Comment: Your working option number 2 (with 1 LoadBalancer + 1 ingress-controller) seems a good one and I would prefer that way.  What is the reason behind using 2nd LoadBalancer in your case, if it works with solution number 2?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin It is more a question of misunderstanding the concept and workflow. I stick now with "option 2". Thank you! If you like you can write this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a second ingress-controller with a second LoadBalancer (and pointing
> the second domain to that second LB)?

**No** there is no requirement for a second LoadBalancer. You can single LB backed by the ingress controller and map the multiple domains.

**to point the second domain to the same first LoadBalancer to use only one ìngress-controller`?**

Yes, you can use the single ingress controller, inside DNS for both domains you have to add the **A** value of **CNAME** value.

From **DNS** all traffic will get forwarded to **LB**, which is backed by the **ingress controller**.

If you are using the **Nginx ingress controller** different domain or hosts goes like in config

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar
          servicePort: 80
```

For **treafik** also it will be the **same**, or else you can create a two separate ingress instead of one.

ingress-1.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

ingress-2.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-ingress-two
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 80
```

path-based further routing you can implement on ingress.

So you over all arch will be something like

All traffic comes from a single point, **treafik** controller which is exposed as **Loadbalancer** service.

All your other **microservices** will be running as the **ClusterIP**, as we don't want to direct access from the internet.

Read more at : https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c

Answer (score 1):

My working approach:

- I use two domains, both pointing to the Loadbalancer (in my case at Hetzner)
- I create a service `type: LoadBalancer` which I annotate with the corresponding values:

  - `load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/hostname: my.domain.com`
  - `load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: myloadbalancer-name`
  - `load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/protocol: http`
- I annotate my Ingress Service with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`.

  - I added the routes to that ingress.

```
┌────────────┐                                                    
│            │                                                    
│ Domain A   │───┐                                                
│            │   │                                                
└────────────┘   │    ┌───────────────┐                           
                 ├───▶│ Loadbalancer A│                           
┌────────────┐   │    └───────────────┘                           
│            │   │            │                                   
│ Domain B   │───┘            ▼                                   
│            │       ┌─────────────────┐     ┌───────────────────┐
└────────────┘       │Service          │     │Ingress            │
                     │                 │◀────│ /    -> frontend  │
                     └─────────────────┘     │ /api -> backend   │
                              │              └───────────────────┘
                       ┌──────┴──────┐                            
                       ▼             ▼                            
                 ┌───────────┐ ┌───────────┐                      
                 │Service    │ │Service    │                      
                 │ FRONTEND  │ │ BACKEND   │                      
                 │           │ │           │                      
                 └───────────┘ └───────────┘
```